# How to translate models in Sails.js?

Tags: internationalization, translation, sails.js

I'm working on a simple app with a few models which need to have multilingual attributes. E.g., a model "Article" with a "title" string attribute should have translation for English and French. I'm aware that Sails.js ships with I18n node module, but that seems to handle hardcoded string translations only. Does anyone have any experience with this or sample code to point me to? I'm looking for a best practice here, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways:

1.) Duplicate the fields in you model for each language like:

```
{
  title_en: "string",
  title_fr: "string", 
}
```

2.) You can add a "language"-attribute to your Articles (so you can select find().where({lang: 'en'}):

```
{
  title: "string",
  lang: {
     type: "string",
     enum: ["en","fr"]
  }
}
```

What way to choose depends on your usecase.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find a solution where I could have a single main entry with translations without duplication fields, but seems to be a rather complicated solution. I'll go with something like your second option.